# I have a wordpress blog hosted on the wordpress.org. i need to customize it. but not getting anything to work.

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress blog hosted on the wordpress.org. i need to customize it. but not getting anything to work.  I am not able to install any plugin or widget in it. please help..

Thanks...

Comment: It doesn't work because you didn't pay WordPress.org to give you those privileges. I suggest you find a different webhost.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress.org does not provide hosting. Wordpress.com do. If you've hosted it on wordpress.com then you must pay them to enable theme customization features, otherwise you can't

Or if you've made a self hosted wordpress by downloading it from wp.org, then its all in your hands... to edit the theme, go to Dashboard > Themes > Edit